# How to add "upload file button" with my existing form and get the primary key of that previous form in the new table of UploadFile Database?

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, http-post

This is my controller in which the following fields already exist:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Rent Rent)
{
    if (Rent.Id == 0)
        _Context.Rent.Add(Rent);
    else
    {
        var rentInDb = _Context.Rent.Single(c => c.Id == Rent.Id);

        rentInDb.tenantId = Rent.tenantId;
        rentInDb.unitId = Rent.unitId;
        rentInDb.startDate = Rent.startDate;
        rentInDb.endDate = Rent.endDate;
        rentInDb.Amount = Rent.Amount;
        rentInDb.leaseStatus = Rent.leaseStatus;
    }

    _Context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("leaseStatus", "Home");
}
```

I have already created `uploadFile` table in which I can get it's path on uploading but I want the previous controller ID to merge with each upload of file and want the previous form Id in the new database of `UploadFile` which I have created!

PS: I have added previous form Id in `uploadFile` table using code first.

I need the code for my controller

Comment: Keep the foriegn key value in a hidden field inside of your form so that it will get submitted to this action method. USe the same name for the hidden input as the foreign key property name

Comment: @Shyju review my answer  sir , I finally found out what to do :) Thanks for your Answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so basically I wanted my form to look like this :
[I wanted the existing fields like tenantId , UnitId , StartDate ,etc from my previous database and then I created a new database for file Upload and made my form look like this !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckdNa.jpg)

The query was how to get the ID of my old database into the new database of "FileUpload" .

so this is how my controller and Action looks like :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Rent Rent , FileUpload upload, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (Rent.Id == 0)
            _Context.Rent.Add(Rent);

        else
        {
            var rentInDb = _Context.Rent.Single(c => c.Id == Rent.Id);

            rentInDb.tenantId = Rent.tenantId;
            rentInDb.unitId = Rent.unitId;
            rentInDb.startDate = Rent.startDate;
            rentInDb.endDate = Rent.endDate;
            rentInDb.Amount = Rent.Amount;
            rentInDb.leaseStatus = Rent.leaseStatus;

        }

            _Context.SaveChanges();

        var rent = _Context.Rent.Single(r => r.Id == Rent.Id);

        var up = Request.Files["file"];
        if (up.ContentLength > 0) {



            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), guid + fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            string fl = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
            string[] split = fl.Split('\\');
            string newpath = split[1];
            string imagepath = "~/uploads/" + newpath;
            upload.length = imagepath;
            upload.Rent = rent;
            _Context.FileUpload.Add(upload);
            _Context.SaveChanges();

        }
        return RedirectToAction("leaseStatus", "Home");
    }
```

In this POST method the existing form of old database is getting added with the help of _Context.SaveChanges();

and after that the ID Which I got from existing fields got saved in the new variable I created Just after _Context.SaveChanges();

and called that value in fileUpload code .

[And Finally this is how I got my Id of old database of existing form into new Table of fileUpload !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/volJ1.jpg)